# System.FinalException when doing an Update of a non-final SObject in Batch finish()

Tags: apex, batch

I am really confused to see a `System.FinalException: Record is read-only` in the `finish()` method of this Apex Batch construct.

I have an abstract super class that takes care of the main Apex batch requirements and provides an overridable method `onFinish()` so that subclasses can add code to the `finish()` methods.

```
public abstract class AbstractBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {

    ...

    protected abstract void onFinish();

    ...

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context){ 
        onFinish();
    }

    ...
}
```

and a class that uses it:

```
public with sharing class MyBatch extends AbstractBatch {

    protected MyObject__c my;

    ...

    public override void onFinish() {
        my.field = 'newValue';
        update my;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The batch was triggered by After Insert Trigger so it was already implicitely passed in as `final`.

I now just requery it again and then update it.